# How can I hide the ?q= part of a url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

So far my page is accessible with:

```
 mysite.com/quiz/?q=4J28S2SA
```

But I want the page to be accessible with just:

```
mysite.com/quiz/4J28S2SA
```

So far I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^quiz/index.php([^/]*)$ /quiz/quiz.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: what is /quizzes ?

Comment: Sorry changed to /quiz. Still same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^quiz/(.+)$    quiz/?q=$1 [L]
```